# iOS face detection in portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I am having trouble with CoreImage's face detection. My app uses the front camera to take a portrait photo of a face. Here is my setup:

```
CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.photo.CGImage];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:context options:@{CIDetectorAccuracyHigh:CIDetectorAccuracy}];
NSDictionary* imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:imageOptions];


for (CIFaceFeature *f in features)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(f.bounds));

    if (f.hasLeftEyePosition)
        NSLog(@"Left eye %.0f %.0f", f.leftEyePosition.x, f.leftEyePosition.y);

    if (f.hasRightEyePosition)
        NSLog(@"Right eye %.0f %.0f", f.rightEyePosition.x, f.rightEyePosition.y);

    if (f.hasMouthPosition)
        NSLog(@"Mouth %.0f %.0f", f.mouthPosition.x, f.mouthPosition.y);
}
```

Here is my console output:

```
{{437.5, 170}, {625, 625}}
Left eye 628 371
Right eye 639 594
Mouth 906 482
```

There are 2 problems with this:

1. These coordinates are clearly not using the view of my app (320 X 568)
2. They seem to be the wrong orientation. The eyes should have about the same y level, but instead they have the same x level

How can I correct these issues?

Comment: They're probably in pixels, and probably in portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreImage's face detector work in the image coordinate space, not the view space.
So the coordinates that are returned to you are in pixels in the image, your view.

[Here](http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.fr/2012/03/coreimage-and-uikit-coordinates.html)'s a tutorial on what theses coordinate spaces are, and how to convert from one another. This should clear up things for you.

As far as orientation goes : you got it right, it *might* be reversed.

When the user takes a picture, whether it is landscape or portrait, the actual image written on disk is always the same dimensions. It only sets a flag somewhere in the file that tells which orientation it should be displayed in (the `Exif.Image.Orientation` to be precise) , flag that the `UIImageView` respects, but that is lost when you convert to `CGImage` and then `CIImage`.

You can know whether or not to flip `x` and `y` values by looking at the original `UIImage`'s `imageOrientation` property. If you wanna learn more on what this flag is exactly, and how a surprisingly large number of people get it wrong, head over to [here](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/)